# Vercel's Postgres CLI

Tags: postgresql, next.js, vercel

Vercel's Postgres is in and somehow I am using it.

So I have like to ask how I can access postgres from the CLI.  In Heroku, I just have to do this:

> heroku psql

Then I could just query the DB like normal postgres DB from the CLI.

But in vercel, I could not find the doc to do it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.